# Is it possible to know what string replaces a wildcard in a regex comparison?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Suppose I check whether a string match a regex with wildcard. How can I programatically get extract which substring replaces the wildcard?

Simple example: the regex is `"[foo|bar].*\.txt"` and say, a matching string that is found is "foo123.txt". In this case the answer I want is "123", since it is the substring that replaces the wildcard. If a matching string is bar0123456789.txt, then the answer is 0123456789.

I use c#, but I wouldn't mind answers in other languages that I can also implement in c#

Comment: They're called [Captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use square brackets, if you want a group. Square brackets create a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes).

What you want is a [non capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) for that:

```
(?:foo|bar).*\.txt
```

To get the result from the `.*` (`.` is a special character that matches any character, but Newline characters (by default) and `*` is a [quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers) that repeats the previous character 0 or more times), you need to put it into a [capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs).

```
(?:foo|bar)(.*)\.txt
```

Comment: In fact `.` matches everything but line breaks (including whitespace)

Comment: @m.buettner of course you are right, corrected my description.